# The $\mathbb C \mathbb Z$ module $V$ has no submodule $W_2$ such that $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, solution-verification

Consider the infinite group $G=(\mathbb Z,+)$ and let $V=\mathbb C^2$. Consider the operation defined for $n\in \mathbb Z$ and $v \in V$ by:
$$ nv:= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
     1&n  \\
    0 &  1
\end{array} \right)v$$
I have already shown that this makes $V$ into an $FG$-module ($F=\mathbb C, G=\mathbb Z$). I also have shown that the following space is a submodule of $V$:

$W_1=$span $\binom{1}{0}$

Now we have introduced the preliminaries of the problem, I am doubting myself about:

> Show that there is no submodule $W_2$ of $V$ such that $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$.

As usual is with such problems, I assume that there exists such a $W_2$ and try to arrive at a contradiction.  for any $v\in V$ we may write: 
$$ v= w_1 + w_2 = \binom{x_1}{0} + w_2. $$
where $x_1 \in \mathbb C$ and $w_1 \in W_1$, likewise $w_2 \in W_2$.
I suppose the problem arises with the zero vector am I correct? So we let $v=0$, then:
$$\binom{0}{0}=\binom{x_1}{0} + w_2 \implies w_2 =\binom{-x_1}{0} \in W_1  $$
Contradiction. These two spaces cannot overlap.

---

Edit:
This argument breaks down whenever $x_1=0$, we then have $\binom{0}{0}=\binom{0}{0} + \binom{0}{0} \dots$
So my argument is incorrect, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero vector is not the problem, all subspaces intersect at zero since every subspace is assumed to contain zero. In your case, these reason it is not a contradiction is that $w_2$ is the zero vector and $x_1 = 0$.

A correct proof goes as follow. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists such a $W_2$, then by dimension counting $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}(W_2) = 1$. But that means every non-zero element of $W_2$ is simultaneously an eigenvector for every $g \in G$. But for $n \neq 0$, the matrix
$$
A_n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$

has a unique eigenvector which is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which is contained in $W_1$, and so we're done.